# Flask wtf froms with framework

Tags: html, css, forms, flask

Let's assume I want to use a framework like https://sdx.swisscom.ch/ to build a UI.
How can I use html forms and sdx components together? I use render_template

So far I couldn't get it working.
My idea was:

```
<form>
   <sdx-input> 
   </sdx-input>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you cant use WTForm to render in this way, you only will use Wtform to validate your inputs on server side, so i recommend to use [Flask-Marshmallow](https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) extension, is more lightweight than Wtforms and work with API's